# How to sort by 2 columns when joining 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables containing bookmarks and likes of images in my Pinterest-style application. I want to create a SQL Query where I want to select the most popular images, based on bookmarks and likes.

I want to prioritize bookmarks over likes, but I want an image with 100 likes be ranked higher than an image with 1 bookmark. So for example the result would look like:

- Image with 100 likes
- Image with 75 bookmarks
- Image with 75 likes
- Image with 30 likes
- Image with 20 bookmarks

The tables I got look like the following:

images_bookmarks
`id|id_image|id_user|id_board`

images_likes
`id|id_image|id_user`

So I want to create a JOIN where I sort by the count grouped by id_image. I'm aware of how to create a join but I'm unsure of how to make the sorting behave as I am describing.

Comment: Order by `<number of likes> times 100 plus <number of bookmarks>`, no? But your example seems to be off … if 100 likes should be higher than 1 bookmark, than 100 likes cannot be higher than 75 bookmarks.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. Can you post your solution as a complete answer with an example of the query you are suggesting?

Comment: The way you describe it, 1 bookmark is worth 100 likes. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I join two tables whereby the joined table is sorted by a certain column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890991/can-i-join-two-tables-whereby-the-joined-table-is-sorted-by-a-certain-column)

Comment: @Sawat: Disagreeing with the dupe vote. The Q marked as a dupe is only a subset of this question. Here the OP's main question is the ordering by columns from different tables with the artificial ordering secondary, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand over rurouni88 answer, here is how you could do it to sort the bookmarks first when the number of occurences are the same :

```
  SELECT id_image, occurences
  FROM (
      SELECT id_image, COUNT(id) AS occurences, 2 AS priority 
      FROM images_bookmarks
      GROUP BY id_image
    UNION
      SELECT id_image, COUNT(id) AS occurences, 1 AS priority
      FROM images_likes il 
      GROUP BY id_image
  ) AS favorites
  ORDER BY occurences DESC, priority DESC
```

You can see it in action here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb14f/7

Answer (score 1):

(Left) join your image table with your like/bookmark tables, then group and count likes and bookmarks for each row. Then order the result by the criteria you have given (100 likes is "higher" than 1 bookmark)

```
   SELECT *, COUNT(b.id) * 100 + COUNT(l.id) AS rank
     FROM images i
LEFT JOIN images_bookmarks b
       ON i.id = b.image_id
LEFT JOIN images_likes l
       ON i.id = l.image_id
 GROUP BY i.id
 ORDER BY COUNT(b.id) * 100 + COUNT(l.id)
```

If you want to sort by the sum of bookmarkss and likes, but have images with more bookmarks before images with likes, change the ORDER BY clause to `COUNT(b.id) + COUNT(l.id), COUNT(b.id), COUNT(l.id)`

Comment: It seems to mo that the "1 bookmark is worth 100 likes" assumption is wrong based on the example.

Comment: knittl: You don't need the `* 100` in the `SELECT` clause. It's a hack for the `ORDER BY`...

Comment: @krtek: I made the assumption based on the sentence "I want to prioritize bookmarks over likes, but I want an image with 100 likes be ranked higher than an image with 1 bookmark." from the OP.

Comment: @PaulSasik: but it's still part of the rank. If I don't show it in the select, the value would not match the actual position in the result set.

Comment: knittl what I mean by "100 likes to be ranked higher than an image with 1 bookmark" is that I dont want to sort by Bookmarks first, and likes after.

For example. I dont want it to be 50 bookmarks, 30 bookmarks, 5 bookmarks, 1 bookmark, 100 likes, 50 likes, 30 likes, 10 likes.

So i'm saying that I want bookmarks to have "priority" if there is the same amount of bookmarks and likes. But I still want like to rank higher, if there is more likes than bookmarks.

Sorry if confusing, hope it makes sense to you now :)

Comment: @MarcusLind: So 1 bookmark is ranked higher than 1 like? Then it makes sense. But each image should only show up once, right? What about an image with 3 likes and 5 bookmarks vs an image with 5 likes and 3 bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

Try a UNION of those tables :

```
SELECT id_image, NUM_OC (
    SELECT id_image, COUNT(id) AS NUM_OC FROM images_bookmarks GROUP BY id_image
  UNION
    SELECT id_image, COUNT(id) AS NUM_OC FROM images_likes il GROUP BY id_image
)
ORDER BY NUM_OC
```

Only issue, which I will figure out, when my the caffeine kicks in, is how to prioritize bookmarks above likes

Comment: They dont have same amount of columns. UNION only works if the both tables have same amount of columns and data types.

Comment: Oh sorry I was wrong, apperently you can make UNION calls if you dont use * as a selector, but specify the columns instead. Thanks.

Comment: @rurouni88: To force likes to sort above bookmarks just insert an integer into each query and then sort on that too: `SELECT 1 as Seq, id_image ... FROM image_bookmarks ... UNION SELECT 2 as Seq, id_image ...` The second alias should be redundant but I have it in there for completeness sakes.

Comment: Well, caffeine I need not, because I have stackoverflow :)
Cheers @PaulSasik